# Swift Picker selection options

Tags: swift, swiftui, picker

On this SwiftUI picker, I need to differentiate among `instrument` selection tag: `nil` for toggling *isShowingInstrumentsAdd*, `instrument` to select one, and... what to do nothing at all?

```
Picker("* Instrumento", selection: $instrument, content: {

   Text("Seleccionar").tag( ??? ) // <- Here

   Label("Add or edit", systemImage: "plus").tag(nil as Instrument?)
   ForEach(instruments) { instrument in
     Text(instrument.name!).tag(instrument as Instrument?)
   }
})

.onChange(of: instrument) { value in
  if value == nil  {
    isShowingInstrumentsAdd.toggle()
  }
}
```

---

Updated. Let me explain what I'm looking for. With the above code, I get this:

[image: Screenshoot]

I'd like to present *"Seleccionar"* as default selection (no selection), *"Add or edit"* to present a new view, and `ForEach` selection to save selection its value. But, this way, I can't differentiate between the to first options. How could I accomplish this?

Comment: `nil as Instrument?` or `Optional<Instrument>.none`. But I don't understand why you have both a Label and a Text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your own enum to encode the picker options:

```
enum InstrumentOption: Hashable {
    case seleccionar
    case addOrEdit
    case instrument(Instrument)
}
```

Then assigning tags is very intuitive:

```
@State var instrumentOption: InstrumentOption = .seleccionar

// ...

Picker("* Instrumento", selection: $instrument) {
    
    Text("Seleccionar").tag(InstrumentOption.seleccionar)
    Divider()
    Label("Add or edit", systemImage: "plus").tag(InstrumentOption.addOrEdit)
    ForEach(instruments) { instrument in
        Text(instrument.name).tag(InstrumentOption.instrument(instrument))
    }
}
```

You can also easily detect the selection of "add or edit":

```
.onChange(of: instrumentOption) { value in
    if value == .addOrEdit {
        // toggle the state...

        // and perhaps set it back to seleccionar
        instrumentOption = .seleccionar
    }
}
```

That said, I would personally use a `Menu` for this instead. It makes sense for the `Text` "Seleccionar" to be unselectable, and the "Add or edit"  button should actually be a `Button`.

To maintain the appearance of a `Picker` in a `Form`, you can do something similar to what I did in [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77328025/5133585):

```
@State var instrument: Instrument?

// ...

LabeledContent("* Instrumento") {
    Menu {
        Text("Seleccionar")
        // when instrument != nil, perhaps you can
        // instead show a deselect button that sets instrument = nil
        Button("Add or edit", systemImage: "plus") {
            // toggle your state here...
        }
        Picker("* Instrumento", selection: $instrument) {
            ForEach(instruments) { instrument in
                Text(instrument.name).tag(instrument as Instrument?)
            }
        }
    } label: {
        HStack {
            Text(instrument?.name ?? "Seleccionar")
            Image(systemName: "chevron.up.chevron.down")
        }
        .tint(.secondary)
        .imageScale(.small)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @Sweeper. Although your first correction is good, your second option is event better: exactly what I was looking for. Great!

Answer (score 0):

Use a collection of optional values

```
let optInstruments = [nil] + instruments
ForEach(optInstruments) { instrument in
    Text(instrument?.name ?? “None”).tag(instrument)
}
```